# Problems with printing embedded maps

Tags: css, printing, mapbox

We have an embedded map (Mapbox) that is set to `width:100%` on a page. Upon print-view, the map scales to the width of the page just fine, but the map marker is not centered. The problem is that since the map is not being reloaded, and only resized, print-view is simply 'cropping' the map to fit the page.

I've tried using `zoom:0.65` in the `@print` media-query, but it doesn't seem to help.

Any sort of solution other than offering a separate 'print-view page'?